# Find files where the filename is only different by case

Tags: command-line, bash

I need to get a list of all the files that only differ in case.

I.e., if I have a folder (with sub-folders) with the files:

```
one.txt
ONE.txt
two.txt
three.txt
three.TXT
four.txt
five/5.txt
five/6.txt
five/6.Txt
```

I want some bash magic that will spit out:

```
one.txt
ONE.txt
three.txt
three.TXT
five/6.txt
five/6.Txt
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  I know this isn't a very deep question, but it was something I needed to know and something I knew would be answered by someone here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ls -R | uniq -Di
```

should do it for you, supposing your locale sorts upper and lower case letters together.  If your local is C, all bets are off.

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

Comment: Wow! Simple and great..:) I suggest to use `find .` instead of `ls` if he wants to find in subdirectory also. For example: `find . | uniq -Di` or `find . | sort | uniq -Di`

Comment: Thanks - I knew there had to be a simple way of doing that!  (For posterity, use `find .` instead of `ls`.  See @RaduRădeanu's link if you care)

Comment: You shouldn't parse the output of `ls`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs. Anyways, you should use `ls -R | uniq -Di ` to answer the question... *(with sub-folders)*

Answer (score 2):

This is closest to what you want:

```
find . -type f | sort | uniq -iD | awk -F"\.\/" '{print $2}'
```

Comment: For Mac's version of unix,  uniq -id instead of D